# Why can't I save my in app purchase?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

First let me say sorry for all the code....I wanted to make sure I included most of the code so you can see if Im doing something wrong. My game has an in app purchase to unlock levels. When I go to buy level 2 it works perfectly but when I quit the app and go back the level 2 in app purchase is gone. Why does this happen? I don't know why its not saving the in app purchase does anyone see anything wrong with the code. Please let me know if you don't understand what Im saying and Ill try to explain it better. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    if unlockLeavel2 {
            let unlockLeavel2 = NSUserDefaults().boolForKey("Leavel2")
        unlockLevelTwo()

    }


  }
  func unlockLevelTwo() {

    let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(1.0)

    levelTwo.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.0, self.size.height / 2.2)
    levelTwo.zPosition = 20
    levelTwo.setScale(0.8)
    levelTwo.alpha = 0
    levelTwo.hidden = false
    levelTwo.runAction(fadeIn)
    levelTwo.name = "leveltwo"
    addChild(levelTwo)



}

func unlockLevel() {
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: "unlockLevelTwo")
        var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
        println("Fetching products...")
    }
    else {
        println("Can't make purchases")
    }
}


func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased:
                println("Product Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel2")
                unlockLevelTwo()
                break;
            case .Failed:
                println("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
            case .Restored:
                println("Already Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {



    var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
    if node.name == "unlockleveltwobutton" {

        if defaults.boolForKey("unlockthelevelTwo") == false {
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
            runAction(menuAudioPlayer)
            unlockLevel()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `unlockLevelTwo()` function is adjusting your game data in that current session and the data will not persist between sessions.

In order to save that state, you can make use a couple of functions primary `NSCoding`,`NSUserDefaults` or even `CoreData` to persist that game data.

To Save

```
let save = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
save.setValue(yourVariable, forKey: "SomeUniqueKey") 
save.synchronize() // makes ur data persist between sessions
```

To Load

```
if let data = save.valueForKey("SomeUniqueKey") {
    // some data here
}
else {
    // got no data
}
```

Comment: Could you show me how to do it with NSUserDefaults?

Comment: I have a question where do I have to put the to save code. Could I put that in the didMoveToView and also where do I load it? Thanks!

Comment: You can put the save code after someone has bought your in app purchase and in this case at the end of `unlockLevelTwo` .

To load it, you can put it anywhere you want before using the variable or even at the start, it is just a variable that retrieves the game data from ur phone to be loaded.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions but my app crashes when I do this.  I used the levelTwo variable in the save code is that correct?

Comment: Im still not getting it for some reason. I put the code at the end of the unlockLevelTwo() function but the app crashes,

Comment: This is the error I get:  Attempt to set a non-property-list object <SKSpriteNode> name:'leveltwo

Comment: Make use of Memon's bool function for NSUserDefaults, that's what you are looking for since u are using a SKSpriteNode.

Run the conditional check at viewDidLoad and load ur data appropriately

Comment: Im not sure you understand my problem. The problem is after I make the purchase for the level and I quit the app and go back to the app the level 2  image is gone. It doesn't save the level 2 for some reason. I don't get how Memon's bool function is going to help with this problem.

Comment: From your updated code, when the user purchases the product, it sets the bool to true. Your unlockLevelTwo function only runs when it's false. Thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here i have set bool key "purchased"

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
println("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
    if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
        println(trans)
        switch trans.transactionState {
        case .Purchased:
              SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                defaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased")
                loadingNotification.hide(true)
            break;
        case .Failed:
            println("Purchased Failed");
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
            loadingNotification.hide(true)
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
loadingNotification.hide(true, afterDelay: 45)
}
```

Use nsuerdefault to remove add here is code

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   if (defaults.boolForKey("purchased"))
    {
        bannerAds.removeFromSuperview()
        customView.hidden = false
        println("Remove ads from 2")
    }
    else
    {

       // Display Ads code 
    }
   }
```

i hope its helpful!!!!!

Comment: Do you get the problem Im having? When I buy the in app purchase for level 2 and then quit the app and go back to the app the level 2 is gone. I don't get why it disappears.